# How can I sort an array of objects manually? Without utilizing the included sorting methods in the Array class?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

I'm still very new to Java and this is my first time using Stack Overflow, so bear with me.

I'm making a program with an array of objects, in this example, I'm making an array of desserts. Each dessert has a randomly generated integer "rank". One part of the program we must do is sort the object array without using the sort methods included with the Array class. I looked up a typical example of how to sort a basic array with integers, and tried to incorporate it into my code in the dessertSort method. The array doesn't change when I run it...

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Desserts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DessertTerms[] yum;
        yum = new DessertTerms[5];
        Random random = new Random();
        
        yum[0] = new DessertTerms("Chocolate cupcakes",random.nextInt(100));
        yum[1] = new DessertTerms("Vanilla blondies",random.nextInt(100));
        yum[2] = new DessertTerms("blackberry cobbler",random.nextInt(100));
        yum[3] = new DessertTerms("apple pie",random.nextInt(100));
        yum[4] = new DessertTerms("glazed donuts",random.nextInt(100));
        

        for (int i = 0; i < yum.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(yum[i].getName() + " " + yum[i].getRank());
         }
        
        dessertSort(yum);
        
    }
        
        public static void dessertSort(DessertTerms[] goods) {
            for (int j = 1; j > goods.length; j++) {
                DessertTerms current = goods[j];
                int i = j - 1;
                while ((i > 1) && (goods[i].getRank() > current.getRank())) {
                    goods[i + 1] = goods[i];
                    i--;
                }
                goods[i + 1] = current;
             }
            System.out.println("\nSorted stuff....");

            for (int i = 0; i < goods.length; i++) {
                System.out.println((i+1) + " " + goods[i].getName() + " " + goods[i].getRank());
             }
        
    }

}
```

DessertTerms class:

```
public class DessertTerms {
          private String name = "xxxxx"; //default name for dessert
          private int rank = 0; //default rank
          
          DessertTerms(){
              
          }
          
          public DessertTerms(String name, int rank) {
                this.name = name;
                this.rank = rank;
              }
         
          
          public String getName() {

              return name;
            }

          public void setName(String newName) {

              this.name = newName;
            }
          
          public int getRank(){
                return rank;
            }

          public void setRank(int newRank){
            this.rank = newRank;
            }
          
          @Override 
          public String toString() {
              return this.name + " " + this.rank;
          }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Before sort......
Chocolate cupcakes 82
Vanilla blondies 60
blackberry cobbler 3
apple pie 91
glazed donuts 91

After sort....
Chocolate cupcakes 82
Vanilla blondies 60
blackberry cobbler 3
apple pie 91
glazed donuts 91
```

I can see that I'm going about this incorrectly, but I'm stumped as to what.

Comment: You've been asked to implement your own sorting algorithm. Copying code online or having someone on StackOverflow solve this for you won't help you learn.

Comment: Whether or not your sorting implementation is correct, not much work will get done with a loop condition of `j > goods.length`!

Comment: Within `dessertSort`, your outer loop has a bad end condition. Change to `j < goods.length`.

Comment: Your `while` loop won't run either and it will overwrite all goods with goods[i]. Best you check out a sorting algorithm and try to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I actually figured it out after some tinkering. I went off of a simple selection sort algorithm and it worked:

```
public static void dessertSort(DessertTerms[] goods) {
        int n = goods.length; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int min_rank = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                if (goods[j].getRank() < goods[min_rank].getRank())
                    min_rank = j;
            
            DessertTerms temp = goods[min_rank];
            goods[min_rank] = goods[i];
            goods[i] = temp;
            System.out.println(goods[i].toString());
        }
}
```

Output:

```
apple pie 3
Chocolate cupcakes 68
blackberry cobbler 86
glazed donuts 93
Vanilla blondies 95
```

The search algorithm I was using as a guide for my original faulty code probably just wasn't fit for what I was attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Collections.sort()`

```
Collections.sort(yum, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.getRank(), b.getRank()));
```

Comment: The op said without built-in sorts

Comment: Actually it mentions only the Array class, which doesn't exclude the other build-in sorts. @GoldRose19 is your problem related with sorting objects, or with the actual implementation of the sorting algorithm?

Comment: that's fair yeah probably better to ask op. I had interpreted it as just no built-in methods like in the Array class.

Comment: Correct - I had to re-read our instructions but it only specifically says "sorting methods provided in the Array class". Even though for my own knowledge, I'd like to know how to do it manually.

So for this I'd say it's the actual implementation.